# Pixel format BYTE_BGRA_PRE not supported on this device

Tags: android, javafxports

I am unable to run run run JavaFXPorts sample applications, like HelloWorld. I using `gradle :HelloWorld:androidInstall`. Compilation and installtion in the emulator goes fine. But when I try to run the app i am getting blank black screen. The logcat shows error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Pixel format BYTE_BGRA_PRE not supported on this device
     at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Texture.create(ES2Texture.java:102)
     at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2ResourceFactory.createTexture(ES2ResourceFactory.java:138)
     at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2ResourceFactory.createTexture(ES2ResourceFactory.java:132)
     at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.PaintHelper.initGradientTextures(PaintHelper.java:118)
     at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.PaintHelper.getGradientTexture(PaintHelper.java:141)
     at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderContext.validatePaintOp(BaseShaderContext.java:440)
     at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderContext.validatePaintOp(BaseShaderContext.java:375)
     at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.renderGeneralRoundedPgram(BaseShaderGraphics.java:842)
     at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.renderGeneralRoundedRect(BaseShaderGraphics.java:601)
     at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.fillRoundRect(BaseShaderGraphics.java:1557)
     at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderBackgroundRectanglesDirectly(NGRegion.java:1119)
     at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderBackgroundRectangle(NGRegion.java:848)
     at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderAsRectangle(NGRegion.java:751)
     at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:572)
     at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
     at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
     at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
     at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:576)
     at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
     at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:477)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:330)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:279)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am using emulator Nexus 5X API 21/arm. Is this related to emulator setup?

Comment: The Android emulator lacks some of the OpenGL extensions required by the javafxports plugin. Maybe you can try Genymotion or [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) emulators.